# How to add status name : success and message after return Data in WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest

I need to return a success status and message when return data in case of success and error type error message if there is error or no data found .

This is controller code :

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPatResult(int Patid,int branchid)
        {
            using (DBEntities1 entities = new DBEntities1())
            {
              
                var entity = entities.LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW.Where(e => e.Patient_No == Patid && e.branchid==branchid).ToList();
               
                if (!entity.Any())
                {
                   
                   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No Results Found ");
                  
                   
                }
                else
                {
                                
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
               }
            }
        }
```

The output :

```
  [{"order_number":2000000013,"Test_Id":46,"Test_Name":"Lymphocytes%","Result_Duration":24,"Culture":2,"Normal":"Yes","Report_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Result":"26","Notes":null,"Low_Range":"24","High_Range":"44","Panic":"","Text_Range":"","machine_name":"Sysmex XN-330","Customer_No":1,"Customer_Name":"Cash Price List","Patient_No":10,"Patient_Name":"ziad adnan","Clinic_File_No":"","Category":"Adult","AGE":25,"SEX":"Male ","Test_Note":"","UNIT":"%","DEPTID":1,"Collection_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Receiving_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Group_Name":"CBC WITH DIFFERENTIAL COUNT","SERIAL":12,"GROUPID":2,"packageid":0,"EXAMINED_BY":"ziad","APPROVED_BY":"ziad","UPDATED_BY":null,"UPDATED_DATE":null,"Comments":"","department_name":"Hematology Unit","branchid":2},
{"order_number":2000000013,"Test_Id":47,"Test_Name":"Neutrophils","Result_Duration":24,"Culture":2,"Normal":"Yes","Report_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Result":"50","Notes":null,"Low_Range":"35","High_Range":"66","Panic":"","Text_Range":"","machine_name":"Sysmex XN-330","Customer_No":1,"Customer_Name":"Cash Price List","Patient_No":10,"Patient_Name":"ziad adnan","Clinic_File_No":"","Category":"Adult","AGE":25,"SEX":"Male ","Test_Note":"","UNIT":"%","DEPTID":1,"Collection_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Receiving_Date":"2020-11-15T00:00:00","Group_Name":"CBC WITH DIFFERENTIAL COUNT","SERIAL":11,"GROUPID":2,"packageid":0,"EXAMINED_BY":"ziad","APPROVED_BY":"ziad","UPDATED_BY":null,"UPDATED_DATE":null,"Comments":"","department_name":"Hematology Unit","branchid":2}]
```

The output which I need as the following :

In case of success return "success": true, "data":[] "message": "Data Found" like this example:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
    {
        "order_number": 2000000013,
        "Test_Id": 46,
        "Test_Name": "Lymphocytes%",
        "Result_Duration": 24,
        "Culture": 2,
        "Normal": "Yes",
        "Report_Date": "2020-11-15T00:00:00",
        "Result": "26",
        "Notes": null,
        "Low_Range": "24",
        "High_Range": "44",
        "Panic": "",
        "Text_Range": "",
        "machine_name": "Sysmex XN-330",
        "Customer_No": 1,
        "Customer_Name": "Cash Price List",
        "Patient_No": 10,
        "Patient_Name": "ziad adnan",
        "Clinic_File_No": "",
        "Category": "Adult",
        "AGE": 25,
        "SEX": "Male      ",
        "Test_Note": "",
        "UNIT": "%",
        "DEPTID": 1,
        "Collection_Date": "2020-11-15T00:00:00",
        "Receiving_Date": "2020-11-15T00:00:00",
        "Group_Name": "CBC WITH DIFFERENTIAL COUNT",
        "SERIAL": 12,
        "GROUPID": 2,
        "packageid": 0,
        "EXAMINED_BY": "ziad",
        "APPROVED_BY": "ziad",
        "UPDATED_BY": null,
        "UPDATED_DATE": null,
        "Comments": "",
        "department_name": "Hematology Unit",
        "branchid": 2
    },
{
        "order_number": 2000000007,
        "Test_Id": 1117,
        "Test_Name": "ZINC",
        "Result_Duration": 24,
        "Culture": 2,
        "Normal": "Yes",
        "Report_Date": "2020-11-08T00:00:00",
        "Result": "80",
        "Notes": null,
        "Low_Range": "60",
        "High_Range": "130",
        "Panic": "",
        "Text_Range": "",
        "machine_name": "Access 2",
        "Customer_No": 1,
        "Customer_Name": "Cash Price List",
        "Patient_No": 10,
        "Patient_Name": "ziad adnan",
        "Clinic_File_No": "",
        "Category": "Adult",
        "AGE": 25,
        "SEX": "Male      ",
        "Test_Note": "",
        "UNIT": "ug/dl",
        "DEPTID": 2,
        "Collection_Date": "2020-11-07T00:00:00",
        "Receiving_Date": "2020-11-07T00:00:00",
        "Group_Name": null,
        "SERIAL": 1,
        "GROUPID": 0,
        "packageid": 6329,
        "EXAMINED_BY": "ziad",
        "APPROVED_BY": "ziad",
        "UPDATED_BY": null,
        "UPDATED_DATE": null,
        "Comments": "",
        "department_name": "Clinical Chemistry Unit",
        "branchid": 2
    }
],

    "message": "Data Found "
}
```

In case no data found or error return :

```
{
    "success": False,
    "error": [ "error code and type"],
    "message": "error message"
}
```

How can I do that please and thank you .

Comment: I would create a separate model (class) with the properties success (boolean), data (list of entity), message (string) and instantiate it in the controller and assign the appr. values to it and then return it in the response.

Comment: @derstauner can you give example please because I'm new to WEB API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a result model like this:

```
public class PatResult
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in the controller depending on the result f. e.

```
PatResult patResult = new PatResult
{
    Success = true,
    Message = "Data Found",
    Entities = entities
};

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, patResult);
```

Comment: error in this line public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; } type or namespace Entity could not be found .

Comment: Entity should be your entity type.

Comment: ok thank you that's working but how to add new line after success and new line between the data output and line between data and message :)

Comment: This is just formatting. If you review the response in the browser under preview, then you should see a tree like structure with new lines.

Comment: If you are pleased with the reply, then please mark it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: what about success = false ,and error message  may I need to create another class for that ?